# How to pass Google Sheets timestamp to AWS RDS MySQL error passing timestamp

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am unable to pass timestamp from spreadsheet to AWS RDS MySQL. I'm not good at JavaScript. Check the photos it has the code and Google Sheets sample.

[image: spreadsheet table]

[image: script as image]

```
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO Data'
      + '(Timestamp, Product_Category, Product_Name, Product_Rating) values (?, ?, ?, ?)');
  for (var i = 1; i<2; i++) {

    var timestamp = values[i][0];
    var productCategory = values[i][1];
    var productName = values[i][2];
    var productRating = values[i][3];
    var ts = timestamp.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
    var month = timestamp.getMonth() + 1;
    var dayofTheMonth = timestamp.getDate();
    var year = timestamp.getFullYear();
    var hours = timestamp.getHours();
    var minutes = timestamp.getMinutes();
    var seconds = timestamp.getSeconds();
    var finalDateString = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayofTheMonth+" "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;


    var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO Data'
      + '(Timestamp, Product_Category, Product_Name, Product_Rating) values (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    stmt.setString(1, ts)
    stmt.setString(2, productCategory);
    stmt.setString(3, productName);
    stmt.setInt(4, productRating);

    stmt.addBatch();
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the date (timestamp) before passing it to your sheet.

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

see example [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4737-google-sheet-auto-update-date.html)